# File level encryption - sqlite for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, file, encryption

I would like to know if there is a way for me to perform encryption of a file (not the data, that is possible).. say an entire sqlite db, at the file level.. in Android and in iOS.

Well, the intent is to decrypt the entire db file when the app is launched and encrypt it when the app goes to background (similar to the device lock/passcode, but just for the resources of the app)

PS: I'm not looking for commercial tools.

Comment: If you just want database file encryption have you looked at SQLCipher for Android?

Comment: SQLCipher does encryption of data individually, decrypting the query results, and encrypting before writing it.. am i right? I'm looking for a solution that leaves the database unencrypted upon app launch. PS: I do understand the risks involved.

Comment: I don't know all the details about SQLCipher, someone else might be better able to answer that. But based off their website, "SQLCipher encrypts and decrypts in chunks called pages, as needed, so it doesn’t operate on the database all at one time."
I'm assuming off that, that when you query, it will decrypt what it needs, and if writing it will encrypt it for you.

Comment: @Nicholas, that is my understanding of how it works.